# Send notification to all user who have a specific location using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have a trigger that fires when an item is creating. Therefore, i want to see that when the item is created, all users who have a location that was saved in the item will receive a notification

```
 import functions = require('firebase-functions');
 import admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp();

 exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
.document('itens/{itenId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

    //You get the values of the newly created doc as follows:
    const data = snap.data();
    const name = data.name;
    const location = data.location;

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Avana - Está bater",
            body: `Podes encontrar : ${name} em ${location}`,  //Here we use value
            sound: "default"
        }
    };
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
    };

    admin.messaging().sendToTopic("newItem", payload, options)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
    console.log("Notification sent!");
    return null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your solution is Firebase Geofire:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/09/geofire-location-queries-for-fun-and.html
https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-is-cool-geofire-is-just-awesome-b7f2be5e0f0f#.x78gjws28